# Is there a way to get rid of the ad for Edge in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com, firefox

I use Windows 10, Firefox and Outlook.com.

Since yesterday I get a (not so) small ad reading "Try Outlook.com in Microsoft Edge. A faster, more secure browser designed for Windows 10." each time I sign in.

Is there a way to get ride of this? I get "No results found" for "try outlook.com in microsoft edge" in Google. Am I the only one with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Settings → System → Notifications & Actions → "Get tips, tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows"....toggle this selection to 'off'.[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, please?

Comment: Added as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to fix this myself using the Firefox add-on Greasemonkey. It allows you to make a script that runs when certain conditions are met, including visiting a certain web page.

If you install the add on then make a new script, and have the following in it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Outlook.com edge prompt
// @namespace   outlook.com No Edge Prompt
// @description stop the outlook.com prompt to try it in Edge when not using that browser
// @include     https://outlook.live.com/owa/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
document.getElementById("ms-bgc-tp").style.visibility = "hidden";
// ==/UserScript==
```

This runs some Javascript that changes the CSS that makes that Edge ad hidden. I'm no expert a CSS or Javascript, this was made just by googling how to do it and copy and adapting code, and I cannot yet confirm it works, because the ad does not come up every time anyway.

I can confirm it does not seem to have broken anything else about outlook.com webmail.
Be warned that if Microsoft ever updates the web page and the CSS id for that ad changes, this script will stop working.

If anyone knows a better solution, I'm open to improvements/corrections.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. Perhaps the string in getElementById. I tried to change it with no luck so far. (Using Firefox -> Web Developer -> Inspector). Now I dual boot ubuntu, everything fine.